# Using webrat's contain(text) matcher with haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, haml, webrat

I'm using the following webrat matcher:

```
response.should contain(text)
```

With the following haml:

```
%p
  You have
  = current_user.credits
  credits
```

I've written the cucumber step 'Then I should see "You have 10 credits"', which uses the webrat matcher above.  The step fails, webrat does not find the text in the response because the haml actually produces

```
<p>You have
10
credits</p>
```

How can I get the matcher to match the output that haml produces?

Note: the above is a simplified example to the situation i'm dealing with.  Writing the following haml is not an acceptable solution:

```
%p= "You have #{current_user.credits} credits"
```

Answer (score 3):

You're right, this is a pain.  I've found Webrat to be annoyingly touchy too much of the time.

Two ideas:

1. **Fix your test.** In this case you want it to be blind to newlines, so get rid of them all: `response.tr("\n","").should contain(text)`
2. **Fix your Haml.**  This is probably the better option.  You can use the multiline terminator `|` to tell Haml not to put line breaks in:

```
    %p
      You have |
      = current_user.credits |
      credits
```

See the [Haml reference](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/HAML_REFERENCE.md.html) for more obscure stuff like this. (A surprising amount of which has to do with whitespace.)

Comment: Your multiline Haml doesn't work. The multiline operator is identical to putting everything on the same line, so your example is equivalent to `You have = current_user.credits`. The `=` just becomes part of the text.

Answer (score 2):

Better than

```
%p= "You have #{current_user.credits} credits"
```

would be

```
%p You have #{current_user.credits} credits
```

since Haml automatically interpolates text nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that something like:

```
response.should contain(/You have 10 credits/m)
```

will often give me the match I want without me having to goof with my Haml. Given the choice between mucking with my markup, which I really want to be readable, and changing my matcher to a regular expression, the latter seems a small price to pay for the more straightforward coding of the view.

Answer (score 0):

There are various facilities in Haml for manipulating whitespace, but the correct thing to do here is to either revise the matcher to be whitespace-independent or to use a filter for writing your inline content. For example:

```
%p
  :plain
    You have #{current_user.credits} credits
```

Or if you need more complex logic:

```
%p
  :erb
    You have <%= current_user.credits %> credits
```

Haml is designed for efficiently expressing the structure of a document, but it's not so good at expressing inline content. When you want to do fancy inline stuff (as here), it makes sense to drop into ERB/HTML rather than going purely Haml. For more details see [this blog post](http://chriseppstein.github.com/blog/2010/02/08/haml-sucks-for-content/).